# Is there any @MustCall annotation or How to make compulsory to call a method for new objects using annotation?

Tags: java, android, annotations, lint

I know about `@CheckResult` annotation & abstract methods. But my need is slightly different.

```
    Class MyCustomAlert {
       /* blah blahs */

       @MustCall
       public void show() {
          // this method shows the dialog  
       }

    }

    ...
    MyCustomAlert alert = new MyCustomAlert();
    ...
```

Now what I want is, the lint (Android studio) should warn me like "`You forgot to call method 'show()'`"

This means every new objects of `MyCustomAlert` class must call the method `show()`.

Is there any `@MustCall` or similar annotation available in android?

Comment: You could make the constructor call `show()`, or make the constructor private and create a factory (creator) method that always calls `show()`.

Comment: I don't want it at constructor. I will call the 'show()' method later. But until then I want the warning...